# Importing Framework in iOS5 Project

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a project in Xcode that I need to use the AWS SDK in, and for whatever reason, I cannot get it to work. If I copy the AWS.framework folder into my project folder, and then drag it into the Xcode window under Frameworks, all of the files under the Headers folder are red.

If I drag the folder from another location and allow Xcode to copy the framework over, all the files are black in the list.

However, when I try and import the headers (`#import <AWSiOSSDK/etc`), it says it can't find the file, and the AWS SDK doesn't appear in the autocomplete when I'm typing out the import statement. Am I importing it right, or is there something else I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to target and click tab "**Build Phases**" and add your `SDK` into "**link binary with libraries**".. I didn't try add `SDK` files into my project. But try it. After you added that, clean your project and then try import files from your framework.

Comment: I probably should have mentioned that-- it's already under there, and I've tried adding it through the build phases menu too. To me, it looks like the Framework is added correctly, but for whatever reason, it "can't find it" and it isn't in the autocomplete...

Comment: Hmm... Weird, now it is compiling, but the imports just don't autocomplete in the editor. I'm going to try and use the SDK and I'll report back...

Comment: while u add the file into ur project,u will get three checkboxes..one is for copy folder to destination project folder..another two is adding reference or group folder in to project...check that box interchanging and then import ur framework files..it will work definitely on autocomplete also.....